# How do I query a document in a MongoDB collection using a key that I don't know the value of? JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I want to basically query a document in a collection and then delete it, but the problem is - I only know the key, not the value of that key. (I actually do but I am setting this up for my bigger project)

What I am trying to do:

```js
await client.connect();
const db = client.db('testing')
console.log(`Connected to database ${db.databaseName}`)

const collection = db.collection('test1')
const allInCollection = await collection.find().toArray()

await collection.deleteOne({ id })
```

But for some reason, it gives me the error:

```
ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

How can I do this?

P.S this is my first ever SO post :)

Comment: you want to query data has a specific key ?

Comment: I want to query the collection to find a document with a property called "key" and then drop it. Doesn't matter what the value of "key" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is

```
{key:{$exists:true}}
```

you can find all doc that contains key of `key`
and if you want to delete all docs that contains `key` with any value
you could `deleteMany`

Comment: Didn't work: [ERROR] An error occurred:  MongoServerError: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is missing but a required field

Comment: I work with mongo but I saw you use mongoose so , I googled mongoose deleteMany 
if there problem , sorry

Comment: I don't use mongoose, I use the normal MongoDB Driver for JS (mongodb)

Comment: do you want to update my answer with mongodb driver ?

Comment: No, I fixed it by doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/rt2uzvjn/

Comment: Thanks anyway though, I will mark this answer as the solution. Have a nice day Mohammad!